# Wifi adapter suddenly not finding home wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver

So, unfortunately this has happened before and has only JUST started again, my wifi adapter (TP-link) suddenly stopped finding my home wifi. Out of nowhere it just stopped seeing it. I can see every other surrounding wifi but not my home wifi. I have checked and tried everything and nothing seems to work! I really need help with this! Any answers would make my day.

Comment: Could it be channel related, with your AP set to auto mode and selecting a channel not available to your adapter?

Comment: How do I check that? (sorry I am pretty useless when it comes to this stuff)

Comment: Log in to your router and find the WIFI channel settings. If its set to AUTO, try selecting a channel.  If that helps, you can start looking at the region the WIFI card and router are set as.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I can't do that due to the fact that my parents already control that and will be out for a while which means I don't know the password,

Comment: Not a great option but considering the constraints - have you tried power cycling the router?

Answer (score 0):

Try to log into your router -

To do this, you can try type either of the following on a device that is connected to your network: 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 or 10.0.0.1 in your address bar on google chrome, or a web browser of your choice.

If this does not work, refer to the back of your router to find an address that will take you to the router page. Alternatively you can try connect a device via Ethernet cable. This may allow you to see your router in the [network] tab of windows file explorer.

On your router, navigate to your wireless settings and ensure that [SSID Broadcast] is enabled. If this does not help write back.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I can't do that due to the fact that my parents already control that and will be out for a while which means I don't know the password, I also can't connect to ethernet because my dad runs a business and is worried about receiving a virus into his server. Is there anything else you could think of? Thank you again and sorry if I sound demanding.

Comment: Im assuming by your wifi adapter, you're referring to your laptop or desktop wifi adapter. In that case, you should go to device manager -> Network Adapters, then find the 'TP Link' adapter, right click and uninstall it. Upon restarting your laptop, the drivers for the adapter will be reinstalled and updated and it should work again.